# Maximum number of edges that can be removed in a connected graph so that no vertex is left alone

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, undirected-graph

I have a connected graph G, defined by a list of lists where G[n] are all nodes that n connect to. I want to find out how many edges can be removed so that every vertex is connected to another vertex.

For example: G = [[1], [0, 2, 4], [1, 3], [2], [1, 3, 5, 6], [4], [4]]

We can remove 3 edges (1,2), (1,4) and (4,3)

I found a solution in that I can check every combination of edges and find the smallest one so that our criteria are met. I want to find a faster and more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Please clarify: 1) Is your graph directed or undirected? 2) What does "no vertex is left alone" mean?  Every vertex is connected to at least one edge, OR there is a path between every pair of vertices.?

Comment: 1) The graph is undirected. 2) Every vertex is connected to at least one edge. @ravenspoint

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify the ambiguities.  Hiding important clarification in a comment is a bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "the smallest one"?  The graph with the smallest number of edges?  In that case, this requirement is already implied by  "find out how many edges can be removed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm to remove the maximum number of edges from an undirected graph that still leaves every vertex connected to another by an edge but **can leave the resulting graph with vertices that cannot be reached from every other vertex** would be

- LOOP E over edges

  - IF both of E's end vertices have degree > 1

    - REMOVE E from graph.

Comment: I don’t think this works. Consider two triangles joined by a single edge. If you delete that edge first, then you can remove at most one edge from each triangle for a total of three edges. But if you leave that edge in, then you can delete two edges from each triangle for a total of four edges. This means that the algorithm you’ve described here isn’t guaranteed to work correctly - unless I’m misinterpreting your answer?

Answer (score 2):

A set of edges in a graph where every node touches at least one edge is called an [***edge cover***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover) of the graph. Your problem is equivalent to finding the smallest edge cover of the original graph; once you have it, deleting all the other edges will give you your answer.

The good news is that the problem of finding the smallest edge cover in a graph is solvable in polynomial time. The basic idea is to first find a ***maximum matching*** in the graph (a set of edges where no two edges share an endpoint) and then adding in additional edges to cover the remaining uncovered nodes. Polynomial time algorithms for finding maximum matchings of graphs have been known about since the 1960s but aren’t trivial to code up, so your best bet might be to find an existing software package that provides access to such an algorithm.